# Select Id where column takes all values in

Tags: sql, group-by

Please help me with an SQL query. Here go test tables with data:

```
CREATE TABLE "Cats"
(
    "CatId" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" character varying NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "Measures"
(
    "MeasureId" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "CatId" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "Cats",
    "Weight" double precision NOT NULL,
    "MeasureDay" integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO "Cats" ("Name") VALUES 
    ('A'), ('B'), ('C')
;
INSERT INTO "Measures" ("CatId", "Weight", "MeasureDay") VALUES 
    (1, 5.0, 1),
    (1, 5.3, 2),
    (1, 6.1, 5),
    (2, 3.2, 1),
    (2, 3.5, 2),
    (2, 3.8, 3),
    (2, 4.0, 4),
    (2, 4.0, 5),
    (3, 6.6, 1),
    (3, 6.9, 2),
    (3, 7.0, 3),
    (3, 6.9, 4)
;
```

How do I select those CatId that have measures for ALL 5 days (MeasureDay takes all values in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) ?
On this test data, the query should return 2 since only Cat with CatId = 2 has measures for all days (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

I assume that I should use GROUP BY "CatId" and HAVING clauses, but what kind of query should be inside HAVING?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this using `group by`

```
select CatId 
from Measures
where MeasureDay in  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
group by CatId
having count(distinct MeasureDay) = 5;
```

Comment: Probably your 3rd line should be `where MeasureDay in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. Then you answer is perfectly working and complete. Thank you!

Comment: @СергейВеселовский, LOL ... yeah. missed that

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select m.CatId
from measures m
group by m.CatId
having count(distinct measureDay) = 5;
```

Comment: I appreciate your fast and well working answer. Adding line `where MeasureDay in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` makes it complete since I may have  measures for other days (for example day 7) that I should just exclude from the query.